How to prevent the ClickOnce trust message from appearing for Outlook addins
I have an add-in developed that installs using a .msi file silently. Both the .msi file and the .exe and .vsto files are signed with a certificate located on a USB key that I cannot export.
To mount the .msi, I use the Advanced Installer application, where I have a custom action that runs "VSTOinstaller.exe" with the /i parameter "path\addin.vsto". If I add the value /s, the installation fails, but without that parameter, it installs correctly although a message appears.
I have tested the scripts from a Microsoft website (Configuring ClickOnce Trust Message Behavior), but the problem is that it generates an error because it needs to have the certificate installed on the local machine that I am doing the test on.
This add-in is going to be installed through the active directory from one machine to several, and I need the installation to be completely silent, without any user interaction.
